# Ajax search through large mysql databse using laravel 5.6.* throws 500 error in windows server 2012 r2

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

Having problem with searching using ajax in laravel in IIS 8. Same thing runs smoothly in our local server (Ubuntu 18.04). Everytime it loads for some time and  throws an error. I have searched through the internet without any perfect solutions.

[image: Ajax Part]
[image: Laravel Code]

Things I tried changing in php.ini:

- Changed the memory_limit value:  `memory_limit = 512M`
- Also changed    max_input_time value to:     `max_input_time = -1`

[image: Error shown here]

BTW, our database has more than 6M rows , which it has to parse through to get the results. How can i solve the issue ?

**FYI:**

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2
SERVER manager : IIS 8
Laravel : 5.6.*

Comment: Could you please set your query ?

Comment: Set the APP_DEBUG=true to see the complete error message

Comment: i have edited the question with code snippet for both ajax and laravel part @BKF

Comment: @TohidDadashnezhad it is already set to TRUE

Comment: Try to comment all eager loading methods in your model because it reduces the performance and and maybe one the rows has an infinite relation for example A is the B's parent and B is the A's parent so it causes this kind of errors. Eventually I recommend you to use pagination to limit the number of rows you're trying to fetch.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion. May be I am just over analyzing, Is the error has something to do with the settings in php.ini or the server itself(Windows server 2012 R2)

Comment: try to add the max_execution_time in php.ini , in iis site advance setting set the connection time out value.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I did both. But still facing the same issue

Comment: could you please share what is the exact size of the database? may I know why you set max_input_time to -1? make sure you are doing changes correct version of the php.ini file.